# phpMailer smtp stopped working

Tags: php, phpmailer

I ran into a strange problem. Since yesterday(or so) the php mailer refuses to connect to the smtp-server. This worked just fine before. I checked if the password or anything else has been changed, but it should be all correct, yet I'm getting these errors:

```
2016-09-05 10:06:43 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110) 2016-09-05 10:06:43 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting 

Mailer Fehler: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Warning: Error while sending STMT_CLOSE packet. PID=25524 in Unknown on line 0
```

the setup code is:

```
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
//$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                     
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  
$mail->Host       = "smtp.office365.com";
$mail->Port       = 587;         
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Username   = "theCorrectUsername";
$mail->Password   = "theCorrectPassword";
```

Any idea what could be the cause?

**Little update:**

it seems like phpmailer can't connect to any smtp server...can this be a firewall issue of the server where the php file is located?

**Another update:**

->SMTPDebug = 2; gives me:

```
2016-09-05 17:11:31 Connection: opening to smtp.office365.com:587, timeout=30, options=array ( ) 2016-09-05 17:12:01 Connection: Failed to connect to server. Error number 2. "Error notice: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to smtp.office365.com:587 (Connection timed out) 2016-09-05 17:12:01 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)
```

Comment: Check the port number, This Google search `office365.com smtp port number` suggests `587` is not correct, maybe they changed something

Comment: I checked it, should be the correct port for smtp

Comment: Read the troubleshooting guide linked from the error message. Do the tests to see whether it's DNS, firewall block etc.

Comment: I went through the troubleshooting and tried another smtp server...got the same result. this seems to be something with the php code

Comment: what does `->SMTPDebug=2` tell you?

Comment: [There is plenty to help you here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting)

Comment: I already tried the solutions of the troubleshoot, but without success

SMTPDebug=2 gives me: "SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting"

Comment: Any luck? Same problem

Answer (score 0):

I think your port number is Incorrrect. Use this demo Code:

```
  <?php

//SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP time zone MUST be set
//This should be done in your php.ini, but this is how to do it if you don't have access to that
#require '../PHPMailerAutoload.php';
//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;
//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();
//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
//Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = 'mail.domain.com';
// if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6
//Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
$mail->Port = 25;
//Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
//$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
//Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
$mail->Username = "demo@domain.com";
//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = "password";
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('demo@domain.com', 'subillion');
//Set an alternative reply-to address
#$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'Demo');
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress("example@gmail.com");

//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'Demo !!';
//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
$mail->isHTML(true);

$msgbody = "This is a demo test !";
$mail->Body = $msgbody;
//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
// echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}

?>
```

Comment: thanks, but I get another connection error: Connection: Failed to connect to server. Error number 2. "Error notice: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to smtp.office365.com:25 (Connection timed out)

It has worked just fine till yesterday with port 587, but now it takes forever to connect and then throws a timeout error